# How to use dependency injectionen and argument in the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class

```
public TimeSeriesBusinessComponent(IContextRepository contextRepository)  { ...
```

I pass the dependency injection through my class ServiceExtension, which I call from my Startup.cs.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddRepositories(Configurations);
   services.AddBusinessComponents();
```

ServiceExtension:

```
public static void AddRepositories(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, Configurations con)
{
   serviceCollection.AddScoped<IContextRepository>(serviceProvider =>
   {
       string createContextFunctionName = con.Get(CREATE_CONTEXT_FUNCTION_NAME);
       return new ContextRepository(createContextFunctionName);
   });
}

public static void AddBusinessComponents(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddScoped<ITimeSeriesBusinessComponent, TimeSeriesBusinessComponent>();
}
```

Later I use my Class TimeSeriesBusinessComponent like that:

```
public class TimeSeriesController : Controller
{
    private ITimeSeriesBusinessComponent BusinessComponent { get; }

    public TimeSeriesController(
        ITimeSeriesBusinessComponent businessComponent
        )
    {
        BusinessComponent = businessComponent;
    }
```

But now I need to transfer a argument from my ServicExtension to my TimeSeriesBusinessComponent too, like ..

```
public TimeSeriesBusinessComponent(IContextRepository contextRepository,. string value)  { ...
```

The string value I get from my configurations (EnvirenmentVariables).

**How can I use dependency injection and normal argument in the same time?**

Comment: where does that `string value` parameter comes from? from some configuration or? its not clear: who makes an instance of your `TimeSeriesBusinessComponent` class: DI or you?

Comment: @deezg I add the information at the initial post.

Comment: If the string value is produced in runtime, you can simply introduce an `Init` function or something like this where you can pass such a string. You can (or rather should not even) mix DI and manual instantiation. In autofac e.g. one could use container.Resolve with ConstructorParameters arguments but even this approach is not for loose usage scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, since your string value comes from Environment variable, you should use `IOptions`.

1. You create your `MyOptions` class (that will hold a value you need)
2. You load a value from your environment (or from wherever) in your `Startup.cs`
3. You register your options with DI container
4. You inject it into target class just like any other service

for example:

```
services.Configure<MyOptions>(options =>
  {
    options.MyString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_STRING_KEY");
  });
```

and then you use it like:

```
public TimeSeriesBusinessComponent(IContextRepository contextRepository, IOptions<MyOptions> myOptions) {

_myOptionsOptions = options.MyString;
```

}

docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: You don't need to inject `IOptions<MyOptions>` per se. You could as well inject `MyOptions` directly into `TimeSeriesBusinessComponent`'s constructor. The actual trick here is to wrap the configuration value in a Parameter Object, because this prevents ambiguity when injecting the values: `string` is an ambiguous type.

Comment: @Steven sure, but `IOptions<T>` are a good starting point if one wants to proceed with more advanced scenarios (like notifications, etc...) as shown in docs ref. But you're right, options object itself could be injected.

Comment: I add a Class ConfigurationValues with the property public int NumberOfTimeSeries. At the Startup I write: services.Configure<ConfigurationValues>(options => {options.NumberOfTimeSeries = 100;}); At my TimeSeriesBusinessClass constructor I add IOptions<ConfigurationValues> myOptions. But than on the object myOptions is no property NumberOfTimeSeries. What I do wrong?

Comment: var v = myOptions.Value.NumberOfTimeSeries;

So it works! :-)
Thank you ! ! !